# How big are the factors of $2^kp - 1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be a prime number, $p > 3$.

Does it always exists a $k \in \mathbb N, k \ge 1$ such that the prime factors of $2^kp - 1$ are all less then $p$?

*Thoughts*

Well we can easily see that either $2p - 1$ is prime or there no primes bigger than $p$ which divide him. But being prime is pretty common, it happens with $p= 7,19, 37$ etc.

With those I looked at $k=2$ and they all work, but there is a prime less than $100$ (I don't remember which one) for which you have to use $k=3$.

Anyhow it seems like a good bet, but is it actually true?

Comment: For $3<p< 10^8$, there is a $k\le 9$ doing the job.

Comment: This is still true for $3<p<4\times 10^8$

Comment: @Peter interesting! By the way, the numbers that don't work is because they're prime, or there actually exists a non-trivial factorization with a prime bigger than p?